# Edit Java Date statement from 1 year ago to 6 months ago

Tags: java, date, velocity

I've been asked to edit these Date bindings in a Java-based CMS, but I'm not too familiar with this code. And there's no documentation for this system.

The following is assigned to a variable named **$archiveDate**. It's then used in a database query to pull in content up to that archive date, which I presume is up to 1 year ago.

```
$cal = $tools.date.getCalendar();  
$cal.add(1,-1); 
$cal.getTime();
```

How can I edit that statement for that archive date variable to pull in content from up to **only 6 months ago**?

I've had no luck Googling this and like I said earlier, the documentation for this system is poor.

Comment: Assuming the Java data type is `Calendar`, try changing the `add(1,-1)` to `add(2,-6)`.

Comment: Well if you don't have documentation for the API then you either look at the source code for `$cal.add()` or just try something like `$cal.add(1, -.5);`

Comment: What is `$tools.date.getCalendar();` returning...what kind of `Object`? `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: Please don't write `cal.add(1, -1)`. Nobody would have any idea what that does without serious code-diving. That's what the static final variables in `Calendar` are for... Use `cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume offhand that its using the Calendar class provided by Java. I have provided an example of how this is used, and hopefully directed you on where to make the change. I'll also write some code below.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_add.htm

I am making an assumption, and that is that "1" in the code is equal to Calendar.YEAR. Changing that you can probably make your code like this.

```
$cal = $tools.date.getCalendar();  
$cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);  //e.g. six months ago
$cal.getTime();
```

Or as one of the comments above stated, if you prefer hard-coded values...

```
$cal = $tools.date.getCalendar();  
$cal.add(2, -6);  //e.g. six months ago
$cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

The document you need is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Calendar.html

The `field` parameter should not be entered as a plain number as in your code. You should consider changing into `Calendar.MONTH` or `Calendar.YEAR`, etc... for clarification, and for future code maintenance. This should looks cleaner:

```
$cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
```